# How to add ignore managed package components in forceignore file?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

How to ignore packaged components in forceignore file? I tried with below but not working. can you please look and suggest to me.

```
**/*CloudingoAgent__*
*CloudingoAgent__*
```

package namespace start with all files needs to ignore.
@muenzpraeger

Comment: @muenzpraeger Can you please help? how to exclude packaged components?

Comment: Having the same issue myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what works for `.gitignore` and should work for your `.forceignore` file as well:

```
SomeManagedPackage__*
```