# forceignore files with prefix

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, .forceignore

I have a bunch of apex classes that start with a prefix such as:

- et4ae5__HelpLinks.cls
- et4ae5__Manual.cls
- cwbtool__CodeComparator.cls
- cwbtool__ConnectionCtrl.cls

How can I ignore anything that starts with et4ae5 and cwbtool? 
I tried doing et4ae5__* , cwbtool__* and it did not remove them from the comparison list.

Comment: We might need more info. I found [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/265930/2984) and it says it works the way you wrote it. Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will be in deeper folders, so you need to specify correct path either fully or with wild cards:

1. force-app/main/default/classes/et4ae5__*
2. **/et4ae5__*

Both of them should work

Comment: thanks @salesforce-sas. Do you happen to know the syntax for if the files exist on the org and not on the repo? would et4ae5__*.ApexClass work?

Comment: what do you mean by org?

Comment: the production org